# How to style mentions tag in react using rc-mentions

Tags: css, reactjs

Example Text:- HI This is @Shubham

In above sentence i want to color @Shubham green and other text black only. can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is rc-mentions not react-mentions